# Why setDecorFitsSystemWindows doesn't work?

Tags: android, kotlin

In my activity, I try to call the method, but the Android Studio doesn't see this method

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

I also use this import:

```
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade your `androidx.core` to at least `1.5.0-alpha05` to use this method.